# requestLocationUpdates returns false only on android API 16

Tags: android, android-gps

I'm having a problem when requesting for location on
LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates

it returns false on my AVD API 16 and only on API 16, and yes location is enable.

Calling this from onCreat() :

```
void startLocation(){

    // first check for permissions
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.INTERNET}
                    ,10);
        }
    }

    if(manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000, 0, listener);
    }else if(manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 3000, 1, listener);
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please turn ON gps",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        finish();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the AVD, Google maps can't access GPS too.